# Get path of shortcut used to launch script

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to identify which shortcut was used to launch a script? Something that doesn't require any modification of the shortcut itself?

I know I can get the path of the script itself, but I can't seem to find a way to get the shortcut.

The need is because I am using different shortcut icons depending certain arguments present in the shortcut, and while I have a utility that processes all the shortcuts present, this utility doesn't get used all the time. I would like to be able to check each individual shortcut on use as well.

Comment: i personally think you would get more benefit out of creating standard shortcuts to different caller scripts, which would call the main script with variables (that you previously had in the schortcut). then you could bake in any logging or ID methods you wanted, a basic caller script looks like this:

    $path = "E:\somepath";
    
    $arglist = '-client foo -email "foo@gmail.com"';
    
    
    invoke-expression "$path $arglist"

Comment: A. Simpson, in this case that really won't work. The number of arguments, most of them optional, is quite high, and creating a bunch of scripts for all the different conditions, and then asking users to understand which to use, is not viable. I have lots of code to validate what users input, all in a single script to keep things simple for the user. And, in just a few cases the arguments cause "changes" which I want to flag by making that shortcut red. FWIW, I have a couple of customers with as many as 30 shortcuts, due to the complexity of what they are managing.

Comment: And, I have something close, in that the Console Title is in fact the name of the shortcut doing the launching, which is available via $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle. However, I can have those shortcuts in a number of different subfolders, so I need more than just the shortcut name, I need the full path to the shortcut. And it's that full path I have not been able to find.

Comment: If you already have a bunch of arguments, why not add an identifying one you keep track of in a file/table/database whatsoever, you might even move the arguments to the db for easier management. All these do not lead to a lnk `[environment]::commandline`  
`$MyInvocation.ScriptName`  
`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition`  
`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name`  
`$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath`